# I want to paginate the sidebar of gmaps4rails with something like will_paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate, gmaps4rails

I am trying to do something like this:

```
@json = Location.near(request.remote_ip, 500).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 7).to_gmaps4rails
```

But its not working. I keep getting this:

```
undefined method `total_pages' for "[]":String
```

Comment: You should really handle this with a full js of your own. Sidebar option from the js is very basic and doesn't support much customisation, it's more a way to show code

Comment: Ok, will approach it from that angle. Just wanted to makes sure there was not something others were using to that effect.